# Memcaching database queries with results in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5, memcached, laravel-5.1

I want to put my queries with results in memcache Laravel 5.1.
When I have used below code, it is displaying some error and query with result not put in the cache. See the below code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use DB;

class Product extends Model
{
    public static function get_product_by_category($cat_id)
    {
        $result = array();
        $result = Cache::remember('get_product_by_category', 15/60, function() {
            $data = ModelProduct::join('products_images AS pimg', 'products.product_id', '=', 'pimg.pi_pid')
                                ->join('products_bridge AS pb', 'products.product_id', '=', 'pb.pb_product_id')
                                ->join('product_category_bridge AS pcb', 'pcb.pcb_product_id', '=', 'pb.pb_product_id')
                                ->where('pcb.pcb_cat_id',$cat_id)
                                ->where('products.product_status',1)
                                ->select('pcb.pcb_cat_id AS category_id','products.product_id AS product_id',
                                         'products.product_title AS product_name',DB::raw("COUNT(pb.pb_store_id) AS availibility_on_stores")
                                )->grouy('pb.pb_product_id')->get();    
            foreach($data as $value)
            {
                $result[$value->category_id][$value->product_id]["product_name"]=$value->product_name;
                $result[$value->category_id][$value->product_id]["product_availibility_on_stores"]=$value->availibility_on_stores;          
            }
            return $result;     
        });     
        return $result;
    }
}   
?>
```

**Error:** `Undefined variable: cat_id`

I am using below references:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PY09dDq5Mfw
https://bosnadev.com/2014/12/27/laravel-caching-database-queries/

Comment: What are you using in your .env file, `CACHE_DRIVER=file` or `CACHE_DRIVER=memcached`?

Comment: I am using CACHE_DRIVER=file

Comment: OK. Thanks. Because, in some video I found that you should do these changes, when I did, got an error 'Class Memcached not found.' That's why i conformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure you pass to **remember()** does not have access to **$cat_id** variable - by default closures have only access to **$this** reference if executed in object context, therefore you need to explicitly tell which variables should be inherited from parent scope with **use** statement.

Replace

```
$result = Cache::remember('get_product_by_category', 15/60, function() {
```

with

```
$result = Cache::remember('get_product_by_category', 15/60, function() use ($cat_id) {
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php for more details.